# How can I get the first frame number or last frame number using cv2 in python

Tags: python, video-capture, opencv

Using cv2 I'm able to get the total number of frames using:

```
cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT
```

but I can't seem to find how to the the first and last frame number.
For example, a clip with a frame count of 100 doesn't always meant 1-100, sometimes it's 0-99 and sometimes it's something crazy like 237-336.
Is there a way to get the first frame number and the last frame number?

Comment: no. the first frame always has the index 0. video files (often) don't actually have a frame count. they have a duration and a bunch of frames that you can jump to by **timestamp**.

Answer (score 0):

Get the current frame index with `cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES`, set it to 0 with `cv2.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)`, then read the frame. Do the same thing with the final frame by setting the frame index to `cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT - 1`. You will then be provided with the first and last frame numbers.